# write file inside www folder using phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I want to write a file which resides inside www folder. I'm using simple write function of [phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter).

My code is working properly in simulator but not working in iPad. 
In google group i found that we can't write file inside www folder is it true?

Comment: I think you cannot write there. Why don't you explain what are you trying to achieve, perhaps people can propose alternative solutions that writing to www folder.

Comment: I don't have other choice. My complete HTML application is located inside www folder. And I want to perform some operations on this file.

Comment: I know how cordova works, you can also use local storage, write (and read) in other folders, etc. You have options perhaps, that's all I say. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Ok. Now I have kept my all HTML files inside Documents folder of iPad app. And read write operation is working for that. but I want to keep some files in Document folder before building the app.

Comment: How can I keep my files to Documents folder. I have copied files to Documents folder using iExplorer. But I don't want to use this way to copy files. Is there any other way to copy files before building the app.